# How do we set environmental variable in java for windows 10?

Tags: java, environment-variables

Can anyone let me know how to do it in windows 10?

I want to ad classpath and path in both user and system variables.

Comment: See : https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Comment: just type `Environment variable` in the Cortana search box, you will get the option as `Edit the System Environment Variable`. Click on the it, you will get the dialog box same as in previous windows versions.

Comment: Do you want to set the environment variable from within a Java application or for your Java development environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Search the web and Windows" box on the Taskbar, type "environment variables" then select "Edit the system environment variables" then click "Environment variables"